# Does Level Shifting for I2C also work for UART?

Tags: level-shifting

This is a widely used circuit for level-shifting I2C signals that will be familiar to many of us here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ueon.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Can it be used for shifting UART signals at, say 9600 baud as well? The simulator doesn't see any problems with that idea. Obviously, UART is not a bus topology, but if you isolated this as a circuit between two devices and used one for RX and one for TX would you foresee any problems in doing that?

I recognize that the pull-up resistors don't serve a purpose in a UART context either (because it's a push-pull driver). But I'm thinking about sharing this level shifting circuit electrically in a context where I might be switching back and forth between open-collector and push-pull drivers (UART / I2C).

Comment: I've used this circuit for UART a bunch with no problems. I was using 115200 baud. UART idles high by default so as long as the driver current is not exceeded then there is no problems leaking the pull up resistors.

Comment: What are the voltage levels you want to switch between? If one of them is true RS232 then I think the answer is no, it won't work.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson 5V and 3.3V as depicted in the schematic.

Comment: Really depends on your implementation, path length etc.. Also most logic, even 5V will detect 3.3V as a valid high level, to go from 5V to 3.3V where you can use a simple voltage divisor with 2 resistors.

Answer (score 3):

The I2C level translation circuit is bidirectional whereas a UART is unidirectional. So the UART can use a much simpler circuit.

For TXD_3V3 to RXD_5V, a direct connection can be used. The 3V3 logic HIGH is above the 2 V or 2.4 V threshold for a 5 V logic HIGH.

For TXD_5V to RXD_3V3, two basic circuits can be used: a two-resistor potential divider or a diode and a pull-up resistor.

The potential divider is simple. TXD_5V drives the divider and RXD_3V3 connects to the divider output. The divider output voltage will be 2/3rds its input so the bottom resistor is approx. double the value of the top resistor. Unfortunately, being a UART, the TXD_5V idling state will be a 5 V STOP bit level. This means the potential divider will always be drawing a current. Much larger resistor values will reduce this current but also increase skew on RXD_3V3 as it charges/discharges the stray PCB track and pin capacitance. The tolerable skew and current draw depend on the target design and may well be negligible.

The diode and resistor arrangement is shown below. When TXD_5V drives logic LOW, the diode pulls RXD_3V3 to about 0.2 V higher than the TXD_5V logic LOW voltage, which should be low enough for RXD_3V3 by a margin (check datasheets). When TXD_5V drives HIGH, D1 is reverse-biased and RXD_3V3 is pulled HIGH by R1. No current is drawn by the interface circuit when TXD_5V is idling HIGH.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLQBzbm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

you may probably want to remove the capacitors (atleast according to my simulation), and add a 100ohm resistor between the input pulse signal and the drain (it removes gate current spikes).

Also, this circuit has a fault that when input voltage is close to output voltage (so its not 5V->3.3V but more like [4.2 to 3.3V]->3.3V) then e.g. at 3.3V->3.3V the output will not be 3.3V, but more like 2.6V which can be seen by simulation.